# Pinging local domain returns unknown IPv6

Tags: dns

I have a weird problem I can't solve due to my lack of knowledge.

I have a local server running Dnsmasq. On my computer (Windows 10) I have Acrylic DNS Proxy which directs all requests ending with .local to the local server. It works great, however one domain respons with an unknown IPv6 address.

```
> ping testdomain.local

Pinging TESTDOMAIN [IPv6 address] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from IPv6 address: time<1ms
```

I can't figure out why **testdomain.local** is reversed to **TESTDOMAIN**. All my other local domains respons as expected:

```
> ping testdomain2.local

Pinging testdomain2.local [local server address] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from local server address: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Comment: Does your local DNS server have `AAAA` record for `testomain.local`?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a phone or something on the same network? RFC6762 reserves the `.LOCAL` name for multicast DNS, and both iOS and Android have that turned on by default. Try using a domain name you own instead of just pulling one out of the air.

Comment: No, no phone or anything. Brand new laptop. Tried on different network, though same result. I'm pretty sure it's not the DNS server. Whenever pinging from the DNS server it respons as expected. Even tried shutting down the DNS server, went to a different network, flushed the DNS cache on my laptop, but same result. Responding with a IPv6 address. I give up. Renaming testdomain.local to testdomain.xyz.local works.